# How do I replicate the functionality of the "Add to source control" button?

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio

Visual Studio provides an "Add to source control" button that automagically sets up a local repo (Git, in my case). Under certain circumstances, this button is not available (e.g. another project included in the solution is itself source-controlled).

What steps do I take to replicate the functionality of this button when it is not available?

Comment: Visual Studio is upset with me that I'm referencing local projects with their own repos which is dreadfully problematic for other reasons. I do not know how to placate it. This seems a personal failing but I do not know what I need to do.

Comment: I am sure I need to rephrase thsi question but many things are angry at me.

Comment: Are the files you try to open local to your working directory? Do you have a .gitignore file?